# Redirect from facebook login to localhost

Tags: spring, facebook-graph-api, facebook-social-plugins, spring-social

Hi Iam using spring social for Facebook login when I'm trying to connect to Facebook api following error occur please anyone know how to solve this

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "Invalid redirect_uri: Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 191
   }
}
```

im trying it from localhost:8080 and i have given site url in facebook api as www.sample.com

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to edit your host file entry:

```
127.0.0.1 your_machine_name
127.0.0.1 your_machine_name.com
```

Linux : `/etc/hosts`

Windows: `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`